# Pydap open_url UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: unicode

```
from pydap.client import open_url
from pydap.cas.urs import setup_session

dataset_url = 'http://test.opendap.org/dap/data/nc/coads_climatology.nc'
session = setup_session(username='****', password='****', check_url=dataset_url)
dataset = open_url(dataset_url, session=session)
```

The above code works fine without error, with following setting:

geopanda version   :  0.9.0
pyproj version     :  3.1.0
rioxarray version  :  0.5.0
xarray version     :  0.18.2
shapely            :  1.7.1
rasterio           :  1.2.6

However, I got the 'UnicodeDecodeError' as shown below while running the following code. The configurations are similar to the webinar [here](https://daac.ornl.gov/resources/tutorials/2021_earthdata_webinar/), around 20th  min, who ran the similar code and worked fine. My default encoding:

```
import locale

locale.getpreferredencoding()
 
'UTF-8'
```

+++++++++ My code ++++++++++

```
dataset_url = 'https://thredds.daac.ornl.gov/thredds/dodsC/ornldaac/1840/daymet_v4_daily_na_dayl_2009.nc'
session = setup_session(username='****', password='****', check_url=dataset_url)
dataset = open_url(dataset_url, session=session)
```

++++++++ Error message ++++++++++

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_7075/147578581.py in <module>
     14 
     15     # Using pydap's open_url
---> 16     thredds_ds = open_url(granule_dap)
     17 
     18     # Xarray DataSet - opening dataset via remote OPeNDAP

~/bc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydap/client.py in open_url(url, application, session, output_grid, timeout)
     64     never retrieve coordinate axes.
     65     """
---> 66     dataset = DAPHandler(url, application, session, output_grid,
     67                          timeout).dataset
     68 

~/bc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydap/handlers/dap.py in __init__(self, url, application, session, output_grid, timeout)
     55         if not r.charset:
     56             r.charset = 'ascii'
---> 57         dds = r.text
     58 
     59         dasurl = urlunsplit((scheme, netloc, path + '.das', query, fragment))

~/bc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webob/response.py in _text__get(self)
    620         decoding = self.charset or self.default_body_encoding
    621         body = self.body
--> 622         return body.decode(decoding, self.unicode_errors)
    623 
    624     def _text__set(self, value):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```